# Norm on space of test functions.

Tags: normed-spaces, distribution-theory

What is $\nabla^{j}f(x)$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow{\mathbb{C}}$ in [this note](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/) which is just after Exercise 1? It is mentioned there that is $d^{j}$-dimensional vector but I am not able to get the intuitive idea behind this explanation. Could someone help me to understand this concept by explaining explicitly?

I also found that it is $d^{j}$-dimensional vector whose components are all derivative operators of total order $j$. But what does it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\nabla f$ is the gradient, $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian matrix $f_{ij}$, in general $\nabla ^j f$ is the "tensor" with entries $f_{i_1\cdots i_j}$, where I used lower indices to mean partial derivatives. So in that passage it really mean

$$||f||_{C^k} = \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i_1, \cdots i_j}\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^d} |f_{i_1\cdots i_j}(x)|$$

Comment: Then why and how is it $d^{j}$ dimensional vector?

Comment: @Algebra: For example, when $j=2$ we have the Hessian which is a $d\times d$ matrix. But we can also treat it as a vector with $d^2$ entries.

Comment: @ John: Thanks, I understand your explanation for $j=1,2$. Could you also simplify the idea for the case $j=3$, for example? I am not good enough in tensor.

Comment: @Algebra: When $j=3$, you have all the third derivatives of $f$: $f_{abc}$, where $a, b, c$ are any integers between $1, \cdots, d$. So there can be $d^3$ many of them, so one can think of it as a vector with $d^3$ entries.